# How to call function from external source from button. [Python]

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I've been desperately trying to get this section of code to work in my program. I essentially want to read in several options from a file, and create Tkinter buttons from those options. Creating the buttons is no issue; currently, I just can't make the code run the functions I want.

```
from Lib import StegosaurMainCode as Steg
...
class App:
    def __init__(self, master, menu):
        buttons = []
        for counter in range(0, len(menu[0])):
            text = menu[0][counter]
            func = menu[1][counter]
            att = menu[2][counter]
            buttons.append(Button(text=text, command=lambda: Steg.func(att)))
        frame = Frame(master)
        for item in buttons:
            item.pack()
        frame.pack()
```

In this class, func is the function I want to call, Steg is the external code in another file, and att are the attributes for the function. I can't seem to figure out why `Steg.func` won't tries to call a function in Steg called "func" rather than the one described in the variable `func`

Comment: How do you import Steg ?

Comment: Just edited so you can see.

Comment: what is in `menu[1][counter]`? Is it a string, or an actual reference to a function? What is the error that you get when you run the code in the question? We can't run it because it depends on variables that are unknown to us. It would help if you read and followed the instructions at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Have your lambda rebind its `att` parameter at each call.

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, master, menu):
        buttons = []
        for counter in range(0, len(menu[0])):
            text = menu[0][counter]
            func = menu[1][counter]
            att = menu[2][counter]
            buttons.append(Button(text = text, command = lambda att = att: Steg.func(att)))
        frame = Frame(master)
        for item in buttons:
            item.pack()
        frame.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `menu[1][counter]` contains a string rather than a reference to an actual function, you need to get a reference to the function which you can then use as the value for the `command` attribute.  You can do that with getattr:

```
func = getattr(steg, menu[1][counter])
```

Once you've done that, you can use `func` as if it were an actual function. However, you need to bind the variables to their current values, so you need to pass them as arguments to the lambda:

```
button = Button(text=text, command=lambda func=func, attr=att: func(att)))
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help. Is there any chance you could quickly break down and explain the second line of code you you put there. I'm a little confused but understand how it works.